# Stream is not writable when i try use a StreamReader constructed by the same fileStream?

Tags: filestream, streamwriter, writable

As code after, i don't want create fileStream twice, so i write streamWriter inside fileStream. But it was so strange that code throw an exception when try to instance a StreamWriter. I guess fs's read pointer reach at the end, but it's just a guess. I wanna know why meet this error. Please help me!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Stream
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fileName = "E:\\test.txt";
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(fs)) {

                }

                using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs)) {
                    //exception when new StreamWriter(fs)
                    //stream is not writable.  why? why? why?
                }

                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you edit the full stack trace into your question.

Answer (score 1):

when finished using(StreamReader r = new StreamReader(fs)), code will invoke fs's close() automatically. So when next using fs, there is a check in StreamWriter's constructor: if(steam ==null ){throw new ArgumentException("stream is not writable")}. There it is!